# DateTime null value in textbox

Tags: c#

I'm having problem giving datetime as null..I've created a simple webiste wherein I have Login/Register..
Database has columns :UserName,Email,Password,Dob,Phone etc.,

Model has:

```
 public string UserName { get; set; }

 public string Email { get; set; }

 public string Password { get; set; }

 public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

When a person registers-Name,Email,Password,I want to give DateOfBirth as null and do insert operation..But making this property as null is getting tricky..I don't want to give datetime as MinValue...I want the textbox empty..
Help is appreciated...Thanks...

Comment: What technology are you using? MVC, Web forms, some other framework?

Comment: do it with some js code

Comment: Does the `Dob` in `DB` allow `null`s?

Comment: Yes, Hamlet..It does accept null values..When I register a person, the view gets the data-name,email,password,dateofbirth(null) and passes it to controller,I have to convert this empty/null DateOfBirth to datetime because I have to do insert operation..In database DOB is of type datetime(nullable), in model DateOfBirth is of type datetime(again it is nullable)..

Comment: When I do edit profile I want DateOfBirth as an optional textbox shown..And when the person edits his name/email/password without adding DateOfBirth, again I want this empty DateOfBirth to be DateTime beacuse I want to do insert opeeration..I can't use string.Empty/DateTime.Minvalue(which gives1/1/1900)..I want it empty..

Answer (score 2):

You can use [default value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) in sql server.
For example run this code:

```
DECLARE @dt datetimeoffset = switchoffset (CONVERT(datetimeoffset, GETDATE()), '-04:00'); 
SELECT * FROM t  
WHERE c1 > @dt OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Comment: I don't want a default value..When I do insert operation I want the DateOfBirth row to be empty..

Comment: When I do edit profile I want DateOfBirth as an optional textbox shown..And when the person edits his name/email/password without adding DateOfBirth, again I want this empty DateOfBirth to be DateTime beacuse I want to do insert opeeration..I can't use string.Empty/DateTime.Minvalue(which gives1/1/1900)..I want it empty..

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly then
you have here 3 approaches when it comes to setting a default value for a value type:

1. Use **Magic numbers** (defaulting then to -1, MinDateTime and ect...)
2. Use **Nullable types** and assign them to null as default.
3. Use a **string representation of the value** and then you can assign it
   to a default meaningful string like "NoValue" or an empty string
       or even null.